# Shoutcast xml file

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I made a script to put data from a .xml file do a mysql database and it works, with a normal file "file.xml".

But on the shoutcast link it don't work, maybe because of file name:

> http://address/admin.cgi?pass=password&mode=viewxml

can someone please give a idea where to start?
the error:

> XML Error at line 1: Start tag expected, '<' not found

the code:

```
foreach ($xml -> track as $row) {
            $title = $row ->SONGTITLE;


// performing sql query

$sql = "INSERT INTO test_xml (`title`) VALUES ('$title') ON                 DUPLICATE      KEY UPDATE time = now()";
```

the xml: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTThf.png

Comment: it would be useful to see some code

Comment: @RamRaide updated the question, thank you

Comment: your XML contains one song. The path to the title would be `$xml->SONGTITLE`

Comment: What do you mean @michi ?

Comment: see my answer. please do not post links, but insert a snippet of your XML. In the future, the link may be gone, then your question is worthless to future users.

Answer (score 0):

Given your XML

```
<SHOUTCASTSERVER>
    <SONGTITLE>Morissey - Dial a Cliche (demo 3)</SONGTITLE>
    <COMMENT>Left out all other nodes for clarity</COMMENT>
</SHOUTCASTSERVER>
```

your code to access `<SONGTITLE>` needs to be:

```
$title = $xml->SONGTITLE;
```